# Can't able to write action in Grid

Tags: admin, grid, data

Am developing module in backend. i got the collection in grid as like bellow attached image. 
But can't able to view particular record data when i want to click on each record to view all the information in magento block format(I can view at contoller)

[image]
The code is: Grid.php

```
 public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
           return $this->getUrl("*/*/edit", array("id" => $row->getId()));
    }
```

want to view data in edit block .

TestController.php

```
<?php  Class Sample_Test_Adminhtml_TestController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{



protected function _initAction() {
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('test/items')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manage Shop Details'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manage Shop Details'));

    return $this;
}   

public function indexAction(){
    $this->_initAction()
        ->renderLayout(); 
}

public function editAction(){
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$model  = Mage::getModel('test/test')->load($id);
if ($model->getId() || $id == 0){
   $this->loadLayout();
   $this->_setActiveMenu('test/items');
   $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manage Shop Details'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manage Shop Details'));
   $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manage Shop Details'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Manage Shop Details'));
   $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
   $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('test/adminhtml_test_edit'))
            ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('test/adminhtml_test_edit_tabs'));

}else{
  Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('test')->__('Shop details does not exist'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
     }
}
```

How can i view this data in Block/Adminhtml/Test/Edit.php

Comment: Can any one please provide the guidelines for  that

Comment: Can you check error log ?